# Controlling JSON floating point precision in scala with Play

Tags: scala, play-json

From a scala application I'm using the [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) to write JSON that includes floating point values, but I want to round the floats as they get serialized. How can this be done?

Comment: What data type are you using? `BigDecimal`? You could define a custom `Writes` for your type.

Comment: I'm using doubles.